# I made a basic python calculator, how can I make it more efficient

Tags: python, calculator

So I made this basic calculator and was hoping for some feedback to make it more efficient/clean.  Also, this was made in online GDB so I cant import anything like turtle or pygame.  Here is the code:

````
#Menus
print('1.Add')
print('2.Subtract')
print('3.Multiply')
print('4.Divide')
print('')

#input
a=int(input("Enter your first number: "))
b=int(input("Enter your second number: "))
ch=int(input("Enter Choice(1-4): "))

#Calculations
summ=a+b 
diff=a-b
prod=a*b
div=a/b

#Output
if ch==1:
    print("Sum=",summ)

if ch==2:
    print("Difference=",diff)
    
if ch==3:
    print("Product=",prod)
    
if ch==4:
    print("Quotient=",div)```
````

Comment: [codereview.se]

Comment: You coud use a `dict` instead of `if` and store the expression and choice as `key:value` pair to create a switch statement that might make it efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operators you use are also available as functions in `operator`. You have 3 things to keep together: The name in the prompt, the operation and the name of the result. You could use a tuple for that. Or get fancy and use `collections.namedtuple` so you don't have to remember indexes for the various values. Make a list of operations, then use that for the prompt and generating the result.

```
import operator
from collections import namedtuple

OpSpec = namedtuple("OpSpec", "name result op")

ops = [OpSpec("Add", "Sum", operator.add),
    OpSpec("Subtract", "Difference", operator.sub),
    OpSpec("Multiply", "Product", operator.mul),
    OpSpec("Divide", "Quotient", operator.truediv)]

#Menus
for num, spec  in enumerate(ops, 1):
    print(f"{num}. {spec.name}")
print('')

#input
a = int(input("Enter your first number: "))
b = int(input("Enter your second number: "))
op_num = int(input("Enter Choice(1-4): ")) - 1
spec = ops[op_num]
result = spec.op(a, b)
print(f"{spec.result} = {result}")
```