# Python For , While loops: change if-else into loops

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

I am a new learner, my question is
how can I convert these if-else statement into for while loops?

I try to use a stupid way and my logic is as following:

1.Enter a list of numbers

2.Use the operands in the given vector in order to do the mathematical operation

3.Output the result

Thanks.

```
int= [1, 6, 8, 4]  # input int
operands=['+', '-', '*'] # input operands

sum = '+'
sub = '-'
multi = '*'
divide = '/'
z = 1
temp =0
if operands[0] == sum:
    temp = int[0]+int[1]
elif operands[0] == sub:
    temp =int[0] -int[1]
elif operands[0] == multi:
    temp =int[0] *int[1]
elif operands[0] == divide:
    temp = int[0]/int[1]

if operands[1] == sum:
    temp += int[2]
elif operands[1] == sub:
    temp -= int[2]
elif operands[1] == multi:
    temp *= int[2]
elif operands[1] == divide:
    temp /= int[2]
if operands[2] == sum:
    temp += int[3]
elif operands[2] == sub:
    temp -= int[3]
elif operands[2] == multi:
    temp *= int[3]
elif operands[2] == divide:
    temp /= int[3]
    
print(temp)
```

Comment: you want to convert all of these conditions into a single while loop ?

Comment: yes, my assignment question is to do the math operation
Input: n = [1, 6, 8, 4], operands=['+', '-', '*']
Output: -4 (suppose the generated number is a,b,c,d, and the result of (((a+b)-
c)*d) is -4)

Comment: i can input N int elements and operands in list , and try to run like a calculator.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69410485/i-made-a-basic-python-calculator-how-can-i-make-it-more-efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, [for loops](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp) is what you need

```py
ints = [1, 6, 8, 4]  # input int
operands = ['+', '-', '/'] # input operands

plus = '+'
minus = '-'
multi = '*'
divide = '/'
z = 1

temp = ints[0]

for i in range(len(operands)): # We need to get range from 0 to length of operands

    if operands[i] == plus:
        temp = temp + ints[i + 1]
    elif operands[i] == minus:
        temp = temp - ints[i + 1]
    elif operands[i] == multi:
        temp = temp * ints[i + 1]
    elif operands[i] == divide:
        temp = temp / ints[i + 1]

print(temp)
```

Also keep in mind that naming variables as `int` or `sum` is bad idea, because it's built-in python functions.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I will avoid using such functions name as variables, btw the output is incorrect , i think it only execute ints[2] *int[3]

Comment: @Bennett.tai That's strange, i've tested this code on my computer and everything seems to work (i've got `7`, `-2` and `32`)

Comment: the final output should be -4  (((1 + 6)- 8) * 4)

Comment: Oh, you meant that... I have changed my answer, now it returns `-4`

Answer (score 1):

**First of all ['+', '-', '*'] these all are called operators..**

You can take help from this..

```
lst = [1, 6, 8, 4]  # input int
operators =['+', '-', '*'] # input operators

sum = '+'
sub = '-'
multi = '*'
divide = '/'
z = 1
temp =0
for i in range(len(lst)-1):
    if i < len(lst):
        if operators[i] == sum:
            temp = lst[i] + lst[i + 1]
        elif operators[i] == sub:
            temp = lst[i] - lst[i + 1]
        elif operators[i] == multi:
            temp = lst[i] * lst[i + 1]
        elif operators[i] == divide:
            temp = lst[i] / lst[i + 1]
print(temp)
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful

```
lst= [1, 6, 8, 4]  # input int
operands=['+', '-', '*'] # input operands
temp=lst[0]

for i in range(len(lst)-1):
  expr = "temp="+str(temp)+operands[i]+str(lst[i+1])
  exec(expr)

print(temp)
```